# using array_count_values in 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have array with patch number and seasons next to it, and I'm trying to count how many patches are in a season so I want to count how many $season[x][1] == 1 or 2 etc.

```
$patches_get = $conn->prepare("SELECT Patch_No FROM info ORDER BY Created DESC");
$patches_get->execute();
$patchesresult = $patches_get->get_result();
    while($data1 = $patchesresult->fetch_assoc()){
        $patches[]=$data1["Patch_No"];
    }
function getseasons($patches){
    $seasons = array();
    foreach($patches as $patch){
        if(substr($patch,0,1)!=1){
            $seasons[] = array($patch, substr($patch,0,1));
        }
        //Checking first number if 1 it is season 1 or 2 or 3 
        elseif(substr($patch,0,1)==1){
            if(substr($patch, 6,3)>151&&substr($patch, 6,3)<155){
                $seasons[] = array($patch, 3);
            }
            elseif(substr($patch, 6,3)>125&&substr($patch, 6,3)<151){
                $seasons[] = array($patch, 2);
            }
            elseif(substr($patch, 6,3)>32&&substr($patch, 6,3)<126){
                $seasons[] = array($patch, 1);
            }
        }

    }
    return $seasons;
}
$seasons = getseasons($patches);
var_dump($seasons);
$fr_c=array_count_values($seasons);
echo $fr_c['1'];
```

Here is also a var_dump of how my array would look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPOp2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I"m reading your question right, you essentially want to count the inner array without iterating through the outer? If that's the case, look into array_column()

For example, let's say I have the following array

```
$myArr = [
    ['item' => 'value1'],
    ['item' => 'value2']
]
```

Calling array column like so

```
array_column($myArr, 'item'); // returns an array of just the values that you can iterate through.
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

If this isn't the answer you're looking for, please disregard.